# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeCollection + ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In another project an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller, the `AccountController` inherits from the `Controller` class. Within this class when I attempt to generate a URL to reset a user's password I have the following implementation.

```
// Send an email with this link
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

However, I moved my logic to a Web API project where the `AccountController` interits from the `ApiController` class. In an effort to generate the URL to reset the user's password, I have the following implementation:

```
var _url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper();
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var callbackUrl = _url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, Request.RequestUri.Scheme);
```

With this later implementation, where the `AccountController : ApiController`, I get an error:

> "ExceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: routeCollection"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to pass an argument to the UrlHelper class as shown below

```
var _url = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
```